# How to make a lookahead non greedy

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently parsing some data which is separated by patterns like "?31" or "?32". There is one Field with an IBAN and the next one holds the name. A sample would be :

> ?31DE16170619340006562160?32Jan Doufe

The regex I use is ([Sample](https://regex101.com/r/R0KuNo/1)):

```
\?31(.{0,34})?(?=\?[0-9]{2}|$)
```

The resulting match is:

> DE16170619340006562160?32Jan Doufe

This result is 34 characters long, which would be the maximum length of the desired value. If the name was one character longer only this would match:

> DE16170619340006562160

That is the result I want to have. To me it seems like the positive lookahead (`(?=\?[0-9]{2}|$)`) in the regex does not match the first occurrence but the last one. How would I have to change it, so that the lookahead matches the first occurrence?

Comment: Use a lazy version of the limiting quantifier: `(.{0,34}?)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot. I'm not really sure, what the replacement of the `?` really means for the regex. I thought this would be the same. It seems I underestimated the mystics of regexes